# Running head in LaTeX book is wrong

Tags: bibliographies, header-footer, indexing

I have a book with 14 chapters, two appendices (each chapter and appendix in a separate file), and a bibliography and index.  This is set up as:

```
Preamble

\mainmatter

include chapters

\appendix

include appendices

\backmatter
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{mybibfile}
\small
\printindex
```

This works fine - except that the running head in the bibliography and index has the title of the last appendix on each odd numbered page.  This is clearly wrong.  How do I fix this up?  I hadn't even noticed this until it was picked up by the proofreaders.

I am using the `emptypage.sty` file to ensure that empty pages have no running head (as required by my publishers).

I'm using a class file provided by the publishers; the relevant section is

```
\newdimen\bibindent
\setlength\bibindent{1.5em}
\newenvironment{thebibliography}[1]
     {\chapter*{\bibname}%
      \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\bibname}{\MakeUppercase\bibname}%
       \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\bibname}
      \list{\@biblabel{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}%
           {\settowidth\labelwidth{\@biblabel{#1}}%
            \leftmargin\labelwidth
            \advance\leftmargin\labelsep
            \@openbib@code
            \usecounter{enumiv}%
            \let\p@enumiv\@empty
            \renewcommand\theenumiv{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}%
      \sloppy
      \clubpenalty4000
      \@clubpenalty \clubpenalty
      \widowpenalty4000%
      \sfcode`\.\@m}
     {\def\@noitemerr
       {\@latex@warning{Empty `thebibliography' environment}}%
      \endlist}
```

This looks like it should work, but it doesn't.

Comment: You don't have to sign with your name since it automatically appears in the lower right corner of your post. And please do consider marking some answers to your questions as as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count.

Answer (score 4):

This depends very much on your class file.  If you are using the standards `book` class the definition is:

```
\newenvironment{thebibliography}[1]
     {\chapter*{\bibname}%
      \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\bibname}{\MakeUppercase\bibname}%
      :
      :
```

If you are using `natbib` it again redefine the `\bibliography` command:

```
\renewenvironment{thebibliography}[1]{%
    \bibsection
    :
    :
```

with

```
\providecommand\bibsection{}
\renewcommand\bibsection{%
    \chapter*{\bibname\@mkboth{\MakeUppercase{\bibname}}{\MakeUppercase{\bibname}}}%
```

In both cases it would give the correct output, but the `\pagestyle{empty}` turns of the `\markboth` command.    If you point us the you class file we can take look.

Otherwise redefine the `\cleardoublepage` command to insert the empty page style.

```
\makeatletter   
\renewcommand\cleardoublepage{%
    \clearpage
    \if@twoside \ifodd\c@page\else
        \hbox{}\thispagestyle{empty}%
        \newpage\if@twocolumn\hbox{}\newpage
    \fi\fi\fi}
\makeatother
```

Comment: I'm using a class file provided by the publishers; the relevant section is

Comment: @Alasdair Look at the redefinition of `\cleardoublepage` above

Comment: Hmmm... I've deleted the loading of the emptypage style, and added the `cleardoublepage` definition as above, but I'm still getting the title of the last appendix running above the bibliography and index...

I'd have to email you the class file, it's a house style and doesn't seem to be available on the Internet for general download.

Comment: I seem to have solved it by inserting

    `\pagestyle{myheadings}
    \markright{}`

after the `\backmatter` command and before the bibliography and index commands.

Answer (score 2):

as others have said, the running heads depend on the document class you're using.
in versions of the ams document classes before version 2.20 (august 2004), the
definition of `\backmatter` failed to reset the value of `\chaptername`, which then
persisted into the bibliography and index.  that was a bug, but it has been fixed.

if the documentclass provided by your publishers was based on an old version of
the amsbook class, it may still exhibit this problem.  tell your publisher to fix it.